# multiple definition of `__vector_3'

Tags: arduino, sensors

The project consist of coinslot and fingerprint and i2c lcd display
the I tried to use the attachedpinintterupt function
the coinslot is at pin 9 then the fignerprint sensor is at pin 2,3 the tx and rx

then it shows error

**full code**

```
#include <PinChangeInterrupt.h>
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>    //Libraries needed
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#define coinSlot 9 // coinslot 5v to 0v if coin passes on the sensor
#define I2C_ADDR 0x27          //LCD i2c stuff
#define BACKLIGHT_PIN 3
#define En_pin 2
#define Rw_pin 1
#define Rs_pin 0
#define D4_pin 4
#define D5_pin 5
#define D6_pin 6
#define D7_pin 7

int relayPin = 4;

String Names[] = { "RAVEN", "Surtr", "Tech",}; //Those are the names affected to the fingertemplates IDs
//The first on which is Names[0] : "" has the ID 1 in the fingerprint sensor

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);                  //Fingerprint sensor wiring RX 3, TX 2
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(I2C_ADDR, En_pin, Rw_pin, Rs_pin, D4_pin, D5_pin, D6_pin, D7_pin); //LCD declaring

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);                    //Fingerprint sensor declaring

volatile int coinCount = 0;
int requiredCoins = 1;
boolean coinInserted = false;
int coinSlotSignal;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(coinSlot, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.write(EEPROM.read(5));
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachPinChangeInterrupt(digitalPinToPinChangeInterrupt(9), coinInterrupt, FALLING);
  Serial.print(coinSlot);
  finger.begin(57600);              //Sensor baude rate
  lcd.begin (16, 2);
  lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN, POSITIVE);
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("SECURED VAULT");
  lcd.home();
  finger.getTemplateCount();        //Counts the number of templates stored in the sensor flash memory
  delay(2000);
}
void coinInterrupt() {
      coinCount++ ;
      coinInserted = true;
}
void loop() {
  int FingerPrintResult = getFingerprintIDez();


  if (FingerPrintResult != -1) { //This function keeps looping and waiting for a fingerprint to be put on the sensor
    OpenDoor();
  }
  else
  {
    coinSlotSignal = digitalRead(coinSlot);

    if (coinInserted) {
      coinInserted = false;
      coinCount++;

      EEPROM.write(0, coinCount);
      Serial.println(EEPROM.read(0));

      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("TOTAL:");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(coinCount);
    }
    }
  }
//Only the modifications are commented
int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();        //Image scanning
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  p = finger.image2Tz();               //Converting
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  lcd.clear();                     //And here we write a message or take an action for the denied template
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();     //Looking for matches in the internal memory
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {         //if the searching fails it means that the template isn't registered
    lcd.print("Access denied");
    delay(2000);
    return -1;
  }
  //If we found a match we proceed in the function

  lcd.print("Welcome");                  //Printing a message for the recognized template
  lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
  lcd.print(Names[finger.fingerID - 1]); //Then print the name we gave it and the -1 is to remove the shift as the ID starts from "1" but the array from "0"
  return finger.fingerID;
}
void OpenDoor() {
  digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); // turn on solenoidlock
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH); // turn off solenoidlock
}
```

**but then it shows the error codes**

```
libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `SoftwareSerial::read()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_3'
PinChangeInterrupt0.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
```

hoping someone can help how to resolve this type of issue

Comment: as you already know from your Arduino SE question, the PinChangeInterupt is in conflict with SoftwareSerial library. this is a dead end. move SoftwareSerial to a difrent pair of pins and use external interrupt on pin 2 or 3 with attachInterrput function

Comment: I tried it sir but the problem if I  tried to use the attachinterrpt it wont detect the coins

Comment: but If I tried to use the attachedpincahngeintterupt on my coinslot sketch it will detect the coins